# Why I hear my voice in my headphones?

Tags: microphone, headphones

I've bought new headphones for gaming.
When I wire it on my PC, I can hear my voice in it.

I've tried to check the Audio settings, I've activated the 'Hear this device' and then deactivate it but the issue was still here.

Does anyone know how can I resolve this?

Comment: What is your OS? What is the connection method? If analog 3.5 mm jack(s), then what is your audio device? Just in case: two jacks, TRS+TS? or one TRRS? If USB or Bluetooth, then what is the model of your headphones? Can you tell what driver is in use? Please do not respond in comments, [edit] the question instead.

Comment: There are several audio settings in Windows, can you provide a screen shot?